# G-SPY USB mouse is not recognized

Tags: mouse

My mouse (Zalman ZM-M401R) is recognized as keyboard not as mouse. But other mouse working good. Is possible to fix this issue ?

```
     xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PIXART USB OPTICAL MOUSE                  id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad                  id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB2.0 UVC HD Webcam                      id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Asus WMI hotkeys                          id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ G-SPY USB Gaming Mouse                    id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

PIXART USB OPTICAL MOUSE works great, but i want G-SPY USB gaming Mouse to work.
Thanks

Comment: What happens if you do `xinput float 15` then `xinput reattach 15 2`? If that doesn't work, run `xinput reattach 15 3`.

Comment: Nothing.Mouse still doesnt work.

Comment: What is the new output of xinput?

Comment: http://forums.opensuse.org/showthread.php/473200-USB-Gaming-Mouse-04d9-a078-not-working-in-linux-plus-workaround may help

Comment: Output is exactly the same....

Comment: Okay, run `xinput float 15` and `xinput reattach 15 2`. Does it change at all?

Comment: No, still same output...

Comment: Sorry, I don't know then...